Is there a way to bulk change the name of a series of files located in a Google Spreadsheet?
I have a Google Spreadsheet where in cells B4:B there's a list of Google Drive URLs with the IDs of the files at then end of each URL (not the name and extension of the files). And in column N4:N I have a list of file names (without the extensions) that would be used to rename the files whose URLs in cellsB4:B are pointing to.
I would like to know if there is a script that can bulk rename the file names of each of the corresponding IDs into the names located in cellsN4:N while keeping the file extensions of each file.
When the column got empty in 5 consecutive rows, the script should stop.
Thank you so much.

SUGGESTION
UPDATE: I've added another version of the script, which extracts the file IDs from the Google Drive URLs added on your list of links (as noted on your question)
You can try these sample scripts:
Version A: If only the fileIDs are on your source spreadsheet
function bulkUpdateNames(){
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var links = sheets.getRange("B4:B").getValues();  // arrays of links
  var names = sheets.getRange("N4:N").getValues();  // arrays of new file names

  var blank_ctr = 0 // counter to check blank entries on the links column

  for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    // if a link is found, changes the file name and resets the counter to 0
    if(links[i] != ""){
      DriveApp.getFileById(links[i]).setName(names[i]);
      blank_ctr = 0; // resets the counter
    }
    else{
      blank_ctr++;
    }
    // terminates the loop if 5 consecutive blanks are found
    if(blank_ctr == 5){
      break
    }
  }
}

Version B: If the Google Drive URLs are pasted on your source spreadsheet
function bulkUpdateNames(){
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var links = sheets.getRange("B4:B").getValues().flat();  // arrays of links
  var names = sheets.getRange("N4:N").getValues();  // arrays of new file names

  var blank_ctr = 0 // counter to check blank entries on the links column

  for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    // if a link is found, changes the file name and resets the counter to 0
    if(links[i] != ""){
      // splits the entire link and only retrieves the file ID
      file_id = links[i].split("/")[5]
      DriveApp.getFileById(file_id).setName(names[i]);
      blank_ctr = 0; // resets the counter
    }
    else{
      blank_ctr++;
    }
    // terminates the loop if 5 consecutive blanks are found
    if(blank_ctr == 5){
      break
    }
  }
}

The script will loop through the array of links and set a new file name for each designated link; a counter will increment for every blank cell on the link column and:

Will reset if a link is found before 5 consecutive blanks are found, or;

Will terminate the script once 5 consecutive blanks are found.


OUTPUT

REFERENCES

getFileById(Id)

setName(name)



Let me know if this works with your case, or if you have any other questions or queries, feel free to ask so we can discuss further.

Thanks. I am trying the Version B but I am getting this error: Exception: Invalid argument: id
bulkUpdateNames @ Rename Files.gs:13

I see, so it seems that the error is coming from the getFileById function. Version B is expecting a full Google Drive file link from the spreadsheet (which is where the file ID is extracted). As such, can I ask if the link you are using is similar to this one: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[fileID]? Or are you using a different link format?

Thanks for your answer.  I have 3 kinds of URLS First one is "https://drive.google.com/open?id=[fileID]" and the second one is "https://drive.google.com/file/d/[fileID]/view" and the third one is like the same one but wih also a different ending "https://drive.google.com/open?id=[fileID]/&usp=drive_fs"

I have created a column with the IDs only and version A is working smoothly. Thanks!

Try this:
function bulkUpdateNames(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange("B4:N" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(r => r[0]).forEach(r => DriveApp.getFileById(r[0]).setName(r[12]));
}


Hei. Thanks. I am getting this error Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp
